# How to use GetModelState service from Gazebo in python

Tags: ros, gazebo, python, state, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm actually working on Baxter robot with gazebo and I wanted to get the model state of cubes I create, so I made this method :

```
    def show_gazebo_models(self):
    try:
        model_coordinates = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_model_state', GetModelState)
        for block in self._blockListDict.itervalues():
            blockName = "block_" + str(block._name)
            resp_coordinates = model_coordinates(blockName, "model")
            print(blockName)
            print("Cube " + str(block._name))
            print("Valeur de X : " + str(resp_coordinates.pose.position.x))
            print("Quaternion X : " + str(resp_coordinates.pose.orientation.x))

    except rospy.ServiceException as e:
        rospy.loginfo("Get Model State service call failed:  {0}".format(e))
```

But this returns 0.00 for each print I made.
In documentation GetModelState needs two arguments : **model_name** and **relative_entity_name** and I don't know what I need to use for the second argument. (For model_name it's block_a for the first one, block_b for the second, etc)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261782/how-to-use-getmodelstate-service-from-gazebo-in-python/) by [FirmYn](https://answers.ros.org/users/30393/firmyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NickVot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30327/nickvot/) on 2017-10-25**:
If the model's name is "unit_sphere" and it has a link name "link", then try this.

rosservice call gazebo/get_model_state '{model_name: unit_sphere, relative_entity_name: "unit_sphere::link"}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @FirmYn ,

as you said,

> In documentation GetModelState needs
> two arguments : model_name and
> relative_entity_name

the `model_name` is the name of a model that exists on the `scene` and the `relative_entity_name` is a link that is part of the model.

If in your scene you have a model named `mobile_base` with a link named `wheel_left_link` and another model named `brick_box_3x1x3` with a link named `chassis`, for example,  the following code would show you the right position and orientation:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from gazebo_msgs.srv import GetModelState
import rospy

class Block:
    def __init__(self, name, relative_entity_name):
        self._name = name
        self._relative_entity_name = relative_entity_name

class Tutorial:
    
    _blockListDict = {
        'block_a': Block('mobile_base', 'wheel_left_link'),
        'block_b': Block('brick_box_3x1x3', 'chassis'),
        
    }

    def show_gazebo_models(self):
        try:
            model_coordinates = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_model_state', GetModelState)
            for block in self._blockListDict.itervalues():
                blockName = str(block._name)
                resp_coordinates = model_coordinates(blockName, block._relative_entity_name)
                print '\n'
                print 'Status.success = ', resp_coordinates.success
                print(blockName)
                print("Cube " + str(block._name))
                print("Valeur de X : " + str(resp_coordinates.pose.position.x))
                print("Quaternion X : " + str(resp_coordinates.pose.orientation.x))
    
        except rospy.ServiceException as e:
            rospy.loginfo("Get Model State service call failed:  {0}".format(e))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tuto = Tutorial()
    tuto.show_gazebo_models()
```

Your code is not working because you are trying to get the model state of a link named `model` of the objects `block_a` and `block_b`.

You have to make sure on your scene there are objects with the name you are trying to retrieve (`block_a` and `block_b`), and make sure the model has a link with the name you are passing as second argument to the `model_coordinates` function (in the example code).

To help you on this, you can call the following three services:

1. `/gazebo/get_world_properties` - to get the name of the objects on the scene
2. `/gazebo/get_model_properties` to see the name of the links (body_names) of a specific model on the scene
3. `/gazebo/get_model_state` to do what you asked on this question.

If you still didn't understand very well, I have created a video (https://youtu.be/WqK2IY5_9OQ) that will help you understand it.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7